# How to Transform Coordinates using a Matrix4

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

I'm using copyRectify from the Image library/imglib. This library does not work with paths. However, I can copy a portion of the image by specifying points for topleft, topright, bottomleft, bottomright.

For Example:

```
imagePiece = imglib.copyRectify(imagSrc, 
        topLeft: imglib.Point(0,0), 
        topRight: imglib.Point(10,0), 
        bottomLeft: imglib.Point(0,100), 
        bottomRight: imglib.Point(10,100),
         )
```

I want to manipulate these point values via Matrix4 rotation or translation.
What structure could I place these set of point values into to be able to apply Matrix4 operations like .transform and .translate then apply the new values to copyRectify?
I don't want to have to manually update each point and I think there is some cleaner way to do it like this pseudocode:

```
// put the point values into a theoretical list that Matrix4 can work with
pointlist = [0,0, 10,0, 0,100, 10,100];

// make new matrix
matrix = Matrix(1,1,1,1); 

// rotate the matrix 
matrix.rotateDegrees(45);

// apply the matrix values to the points in the list and return an updated list
rotatedList = matrix.apply(pointlist); 

// used the new rotated list values in copyRectify
...
```

Once I can get the points into a proper structure that can be manipulated by a matrix, then the rest will fall in place.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use this as a starting point. I used Vector and Matrix4 from the [vector_math](https://pub.dev/packages/vector_math) library. I used 4 vectors for each point in rectangle and applied a Matrix4 transformed matrix to each point. I'm not sure if this is correct, but It did add rotation, but not in the way I expected. It rotated the whole copied piece of the image instead of just rotating the selection.

```
 // initialize integers for initial points 
 // x2 is width ; y2 is height
 x1=0; y0=y; x2=100; y2=100;

// create 4 points of a rectangle for topLeft to bottomRight
  imglib.Point p1 = imglib.Point(x1, y1);
  imglib.Point p2 = imglib.Point(x2, y1);
  imglib.Point p3 = imglib.Point(x1, y2); 
  imglib.Point p4 = imglib.Point(x2, y2);

// put the 4 points in 4 vectors
  vector_math.Vector3 v1 = vector_math.Vector3(x1.toDouble() , y1.toDouble(), 1);
  vector_math.Vector3 v2 = vector_math.Vector3(x2.toDouble() , y1.toDouble(), 1);
  vector_math.Vector3 v3 = vector_math.Vector3(x1.toDouble() , y2.toDouble(), 1);
  vector_math.Vector3 v4 = vector_math.Vector3(x2.toDouble() , y2.toDouble(), 1);

// Create a matrix4, rotate it and apply it to all 4 points/vectors
 vector_math.Matrix4  T = vector_math.Matrix4.rotationZ(vector_math.radians(45));  
  v1 = T.transform3(v1);
  v2 = T.transform3(v2);
  v3 = T.transform3(v3);
  v4 = T.transform3(v4); 

// pull the new rotated point values out of the vectors: 
  p1.x = v1[0];
  p1.y =v1[1];
  p2.x = v2[0];
  p2.y =v2[1];
  p3.x = v3[0];
  p3.y =v3[1];
  p4.x = v4[0];
  p4.y =v4[1];

// copyRectify the source image with transformed points
imglib.Image angledSlice = imglib.copyRectify(
        srcImage, 
        topLeft: p1, 
        topRight: p2, 
        bottomLeft: p3, 
        bottomRight: p4,
         );
```